# Test not creating new guideline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When running my test it's not actually creating a new guideline.  I can't see what I'm missing at all as I have all the attributes...

```
1) Failure:
test_should_create_guideline_when_logged_in(GuidelinesControllerTest) [test/functional/guidelines_controller_test.rb:47]:
"Guideline.count" didn't change by 1.
<4> expected but was
<3>.
```

**MODELS guideline.rb**

```
attr_accessible :content, :hospital, :title, :user_id, :guideline_id, :specialty
```

**guidelines_controller_test.rb**

```
test "should create guideline when logged in" do
    sign_in users(:testuser)
    assert_difference('Guideline.count') do
      post :create, guideline: { content: @guideline.content, hospital: @guideline.hospital, title: @guideline.title, user_id: users(:testuser).id, specialty: @guideline.specialty }
    end

    assert_redirected_to guideline_path(assigns(:guideline))

  end
```

**fixtures/users.yml**

```
testuser:
  first_name: "Jonny"
  last_name: "Rotten"
  email: "jonnyrotten@gmail.com"
  base_hospital: "Rottem Hospital"
  profile_name: "jjrotten"
  encrypted_password: "password"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your test where is `@guideline` getting its attributes from? I've always used `rspec` instead of Rails' test suite so not sure, but would think you would need to do something like:

```
post :create, guideline: { content: "This is the content", hospital: "Children's hospital", title: ... }
```

Correct me if I'm wrong...